# Python - Copying data from one file to another file

Tags: python

I am trying to copy the content of one file to another.

The script successfully copies content to the file but when I try to run `READ` command with the output file to print the output, it is blank.

```
from sys import argv
script, inputFile, outputFile = argv
inFile = open(inputFile)
inData = inFile.read()
outFile = open(outputFile, 'w+')
outFile.write(inData)
print("The new data is:\n",outFile.read())
inFile.close()
outFile.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to return to the beginning of `outFile` after writing to it.
So inserting `outFile.seek(0)` should fix your issues.

Comment: Thank uu soooo much

Answer (score 2):

After the `write` operation the file pointer is at the end of file so you'd need to reset it to the start. Also, the filesystem IO buffers may not have been flushed at that point (you haven't closed the file yet)...

Simple solution: close the outFile and reopen it for reading.

As a side note: always make sure you DO close your files *whatever happens*, specially when writing, else you may end up with corrupted data. The simplest way is the `with` statement:

```
with open(...) as infile, (...) as outfile:
    outfile.write(infile.read())

# at this point both files have been automagically closed
```

Comment: `seek` is a much more elegant solution that close and reopen, works much faster

Answer (score 0):

After you are done writing, file pointer is at the end of the file, so no data is there. Reposition pointer to start of the file.

Comment: Thank uu soooo much